# Dask computation never ending

Tags: python, cluster-computing, dask

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np  
from dask.distributed import Client  
from dask.jobqueue import PBSCluster  
import dask.array as da

cluster = PBSCluster(processes=1, cores=8, memory="40GB", 
                     local directory='$TMPDIR',   
                     walltime='1:00:00', interface='ib0')  

task = client.submit(lambda: np.random.uniform(size=(623000, 73, 41)))
arr = da.from_delayed(task, shape=(623000, 73, 41), dtype=np.float32)
res = client.compute(arr)

res.result()
```

The process is not finished. It is always restarted and is only performed by one worker.

What is wrong with the code?
Is it possible to distribute it to all the cores?

Comment: Just to point out that you are passing a Future object to function from_delayed. You should pass one or more delayed objects - read the docs about dask.delayed.

Answer (score 0):

> cluster = PBSCluster(processes=1, cores=8, memory="40GB",

You are requesting a single worker with 8 cores, it might be a good idea to have multiple workers.

> `task = client.submit(lambda: np.random.uniform(size=(623000, 73, 41)))`

In this line you are asking the worker to create the array with a large size of about 2 bln numbers. A better way to achieve this would be to split work among multiple workers with `da.random.random`.

> res = client.compute(arr)

You are asking a worker to compute the dask array, but this might not be ideal, a better approach would be to ask the worker to compute some object of interest that will typically of a reduced size.